# Conditional Filtering of table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have certain requirement which I am tryin to implement with help of Power BI.
I have data which looks something like as shown below:

```
Equipment   Date         Val
AV001   2/6/19 12:10 AM  24
AV001   2/6/19 12:12 AM  22
AV001   2/6/19 12:20 AM  32
AV001   4/6/19 12:24 AM  28
AV001   4/6/19 12:25 AM  25
AV001   4/6/19 12:28 AM  27
AV002   5/6/19 12:00 AM  25
AV002   5/6/19 12:10 AM  24
AV002   6/6/19 12:12 AM  23
AV003   7/6/19 12:03 AM  29
AV003   7/6/19 12:05 AM  26
AV003   7/6/19 12:06 AM  24
AV003   7/6/19 12:09 AM  22
```

I want to create a table out of this which will be having Equipment, Date & Time with its value.
Like shown below:

```
AV001   2/6/19 12:20 AM  32
AV001   4/6/19 12:28 AM  27
AV002   5/6/19 12:10 AM  24
AV002   6/6/19 12:12 AM  23
AV003   7/6/19 12:09 AM  22
```

The desired table should have Equipment , date with latest time and its corresponding Val.

Kindly let me know any possible way to get the desired table.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your post to use text instead of images for your data tables.

Comment: @AlexisOlson -Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part here is that you need to group on date but there isn't a column for that. Here's one possibility though where I use INT to truncate the datetime column to just a date.

```
FILTER (
    Table1,
    Table1[Date]
        = CALCULATE (
            MAX ( Table1[Date] ),
            FILTER (
                Table1,
                Table1[Equipment] = EARLIER ( Table1[Equipment] ) &&
                INT ( Table1[Date] ) = INT ( EARLIER ( Table1[Date] ) )
            )
        )
)
```

If you added `INT ( Table1[Date] )` as a calculated column to `Table1`, then it's a bit simpler:

```
FILTER (
    Table1,
    Table1[Date]
        = CALCULATE (
            MAX ( Table1[Date] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Equipment], Table1[DateInt] )
        )
)
```

Comment: I had actually split the date col to date and its time component.....